# How to reuse XAML code blocks without binding?

Tags: xaml, templates, custom-controls, windows-store-apps

I have this XAML code block:

```
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <TextBlock Text="Hello " />
        <TextBlock Text="World" />
    </StackPanel>
```

I would like to define this block (for example in **/Common/CustomStyles.xaml**) to include it on different XAML pages. How does it work?

I do not need a DataTemplate or something similar because the text is static.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could put it in a [user control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.usercontrol.aspx) and re-use it that way. If it's just the text you are interested in then you could use a [resource file](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh965329.aspx) - this would update the textbox on any screen as long as it had the right uid.